# How database records are stored on disk?

Tags: database, storage, disk

If I have a databases with multiple tables, how are they stored on the disk?

Who decides the most efficient way of storing them?

any relevant/text/article?

Answer (score 3):

They are completely and 100% database vendor dependent. Each DB decides what's the best option to store data on disk.

There are a lot of 80's paper that talk about it. Search them in [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com).

Comment: And further, the DB may offer different storage methods: MySQL for example has several of them, that you can choose per table.